# SonarQube Issue: Adding CultureInfo inside Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, sonarqube, cultureinfo

I am working on SonarQube issues on my .net core application. I have an issue with the sonarQube report which asked to add cultural info in Convert Methods like ToString(), ToUpper(), ToLower(), etc inside the LINQ Queries.

[image]

query example:

```
var query = from emp in context.Employees
            where emp.name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper()
            select emp;
```

If we add `name.ToUpper(new CultureInfo("en-US", false))` then Query will break with the below error. I don't want to convert this query into AsEnumerable before applying this condition.

> could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'string.ToUpper' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: *Don't* use `emp.name.ToUpper()` to begin with. That's the real bug. This will prevent the database from using any indexes that cover that field. If you want case-insensitive search, ensure the column uses a case-insensitive collation. In SQL Server, that's the default.

Comment: If you have 100K employee rows, `emp.Name.ToUpper()` will cause the server to scan all 100K rows to calculate the value of `Name` before filtering. Simply removing `ToUpper()` will use a single index seek

Comment: Case sensitivity and collations in EF Core and databases in general are explained in [Collations and Case Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity), with an explicit warning against using `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()`: `Overriding case-sensitivity in a query via EF.Functions.Collate (or by calling string.ToLower) can have a very significant impact on your application's performance.`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `emp.Name.ToUpper()` in the first place. That's the *real*, Godzila-sized bug. SonarQube complains about the mosquito sitting on Godzila's front right fingernail, the middle one. And the proposed solution is to go swat it.

Case sensitivity and collations in EF Core and databases in general are explained in [Collations and Case Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity), with an explicit warning against using `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()`:

> Overriding case-sensitivity in a query via EF.Functions.Collate (or by calling string.ToLower) can have a very significant impact on your application's performance.

Using `ToUpper()` prevents the database from using any indexes that cover this column. That means that instead of making a single Index Seek to find one row in a 100K row table, the server will now have to scan all 100K rows, calculate the outcome of `UPPER()` and compare it to the parameter.

Indexes are created from the actual column values, using the columns case-sensitivity rules specified by its collation. In SQL Server, the default is to use a case-*in*sensitive collation. In other databases, it's usually case-sensitive.

You can force a query to use a different collation with `EF.Functions.Collate` but that still prevents the server from using indexes. In some databases you can create indexes with a *different* collation. In both cases, the server will calculate the results and store them in the index. In other databases you can create a computed column based on the original's contents with a case-insensitive collation and index it. You'll have to change the query to use the new case-insensitive column to take advantage of the index